# Communication between windows with python matplotlib using gtk.WindowGroup

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am developing an application in python which plots information using **matplotlib**, **numpy** and **gtk**. I am plotting numpy data using matplotlib, the user can change some parameters in widget to modify the plot

For design reasons I want to separate the plot (and data) from the control GUI, then I am plotting the data in one window and I have the controls in a separated window. In **gtk** I found the *WindowGroup* widget that looks can send data over multiple windows, however I cannot find the how!

The following code shows a simplification of the problem: I plot a sine in a window, the user can modify the variable *fm* in the window with the vertical adjustment bar (event). When I run the script I can see that the event (move the vertical adjustment bar) triggers the function but does't actualize the plot.

How can change the plot? or send messages between two windows using the *WindowGroup* widget?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg \
    import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas

def update_hscale(event):
    global t    
    fm = hscale.get_value()
    y_new = numpy.sin(2*fm*t)
    l.set_ydata(y_new)
    plt.draw()
    print "doing fm=", fm


# define the window group
window_group=gtk.WindowGroup()

# matplotlib plot in window 1
fm = 5.0
t = numpy.arange(200)
y = numpy.sin(2*fm*t)
fig = plt.figure(1)  
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
l, = ax.plot(t, y)

win1 = gtk.Window()
win1.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
win1.set_default_size(800,300)
vbox1 = gtk.VBox()
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
vbox1.pack_start(canvas, fill=True)
win1.add(vbox1)

# controls in window 2
win2 = gtk.Window()   
vbox2 = gtk.VBox()    
adj = gtk.Adjustment(0.0, -5, 5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
hscale = gtk.HScale(adj)
hscale.set_size_request(200, 30)
vbox2.pack_start(hscale)
hscale.connect("value-changed", update_hscale)
win2.add(vbox2)

# adding windows to window_group
window_group.add_window(win1)   
window_group.add_window(win2)   

win1.set_default_size(400,300)
win1.show_all()
win2.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, first I deleted all the `gtk.WindowGroup` stuff:

- `window_group=gtk.WindowGroup()`
- `window_group.add_window(win1)`
- `window_group.add_window(win2)`)

and I redraw in the `canvas` in the function `update_hscale` not in the plot `l`:

```
def update_hscale(event):
    global t    
    fm = hscale.get_value()
    y_new = numpy.sin(2*fm*t)
    l.set_ydata(y_new)
    canvas.draw()
    print "doing fm=", fm
```